# What else exception we should catch for ZipFile.open

Tags: python, exception, zip

I am using Python 2.7.

Based on the document [ZipFile.open](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html), I am not able to find which exception should be caught when we call the ZipFile.open.

```
    try:
        with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file_name, "r") as f_handle:
             for data_file_name in f_handle.namelist():
                try:
                    with f_handle.open(data_file_name, "rU") as file_obj:
                        pass
                except (RuntimeError), e:
                        pass
    except (zipfile.BadZipfile, zipfile.LargeZipFile), e:
        pass
```

Comment: What happens when you try to open a bogus file? That should give you a hint.

Comment: @jathanism, my OP is related to catch which exception rather than why we should catch exception.

Comment: @q0987: he meant that you could determine empirically which exceptions are thrown by trying invalid operations, and seeing what gets thrown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you need to catch exceptions at all?  Your code shows catching `RuntimeError`: what will you do if that exception is raised?  Generally, the best thing is to not catch exceptions unless you know what you might do about them.